# Why is Google Sheets API giving me an invalid_scope error only when I deploy on OpenShift?

Tags: java, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-java-client

I am trying to append to an existing Google Sheet from my Java application and I keep getting an error saying "Empty or missing scope not allowed."

The odd thing to me is that when I only get this error when I deploy my app into OpenShift. I created a test case to run this same code locally and the Google Sheet was actually updated without issue.

So before I go chucking this laptop off the roof of the building, can someone please help me see what I am doing wrong?

```
public class SpreadsheetClient {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpreadsheetClient.class);
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "My App";
    private static final String START_RANGE = "A2";
    private static final String VALUE_INPUT_OPTION = "RAW";
    private static final String INSERT_DATA_OPTION = "INSERT_ROWS";


    private Sheets sheets;

    public SpreadsheetClient(String certPath) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        sheets = new Sheets.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, GoogleUtil.getGoogleCredential(certPath, SCOPES))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
    }

    public void appendRows(String sheetId, List<List<Object>> values, Handler<AsyncResult<Void>> handler) {
        try {
            AppendValuesResponse response = sheets.spreadsheets().values().append(sheetId, START_RANGE, new ValueRange().setValues(values))
                    .setValueInputOption(VALUE_INPUT_OPTION)
                    .setInsertDataOption(INSERT_DATA_OPTION)
                    .execute();

            if (response.getUpdates().getUpdatedRows() == values.size()) {
                handler.handle(Future.succeededFuture());
            }
            else {
                LOG.error("Expected to update {} rows, updated {} instead", values.size(), response.getUpdates().getUpdatedRows());
                JsonArray updateValues = new JsonArray(response.getUpdates().getUpdatedData().getValues());
                LOG.debug("The update values are {}", updateValues);
                handler.handle(ServiceException.fail(NOT_ENOUGH_ROWS_UPDATED.code(), updateValues.encode()));
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            LOG.error("Failed to append to spreadsheet", ex);
            handler.handle(Future.failedFuture(ex));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my credential file (obviously with the real creds stripped out):

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "account",
  "private_key_id": "an_id",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nstuff\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "service@account.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "another_id",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/service%40account.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Comment: have you made sure the credential file is actually used when you are testing in local? sometimes google sdk automatically fetches your local credential instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was actually my own stupidity. I'm posting the answer here so that hopefully someone else will find this useful in the future.

I forgot that GoogleUtil is actually a utility class that we wrote and once I inspected it, I realized that the deployed version of my app is reading the creds from a file while the tests were reading the creds from the classpath. The code for when I read from a file did not add scopes, whereas the code to read from the classpath did, hence my seemingly bizarre results.

Here's the bad code:

```
public class GoogleUtil {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GoogleUtil.class);

    private GoogleUtil() {}

    public static GoogleCredential getGoogleCredential(String certPath, List<String> scopes) {
        GoogleCredential googleCredential;
        try {
            googleCredential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream(certPath));
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            try {
                LOG.info("The certificate file {} was not found, trying to find it in the class path", certPath);
                googleCredential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(DriveClient.class.getResourceAsStream("/google-ambassador-service-account.json")).createScoped(scopes);
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                LOG.error("Could not find the file {}", certPath);
                googleCredential = new GoogleCredential();
            }
        }

        return googleCredential;
    }
}
```

My fix:

```
public class GoogleUtil {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GoogleUtil.class);

    private GoogleUtil() {}

    public static GoogleCredential getGoogleCredential(String certPath, List<String> scopes) {
        GoogleCredential googleCredential;
        try {
            googleCredential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream(certPath)).createScoped(scopes);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            LOG.error("Could not find the file {}", certPath);
            googleCredential = new GoogleCredential();
        }

        return googleCredential;
    }
}
```